# Setting up Google login in production environment

Tags: meteor, google-signin

Google asks for "Authorized Java Script Origin" & "Authorized Redirect URL" which is given to us by Meteor as follows `https://localhost:3000` & `https://localhost:3000/_ouath/google` Respectively.

My concern now is, to what URL's should I change them in production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use your domain (or IP address, whichever you use to access your website) instead of `localhost:3000`.

E.g. if you deploy your app to `example.com` your "Authorized Java Script Origin" & "Authorized Redirect URL" would be
`https://example.com` & `https://example.com/_oauth/google`

**Note:** you use `https` in your example links, so that's what I did too. Make sure your website has it set up, otherwise it won't work. If you are not sure what it is and how to do it, just use `http` instead of `https` everywhere and change it back after/if you set it up.

Also be careful with the ports. You might need to use `example.com:3000` depending on how you deploy your app.